# Usage of 'split'

Tags: word-usage, verbs, nouns

In a book, I encountered this sentence:

> Kosovo was a province of Yugoslavia before **its** split.

This sentence portrays *split* as a noun/action.

Now, I usually encounter *split* as:

> Kosovo was a province of Yugoslavia before **it** split.

This portrays *split* as a verb.

So, which is right, the first one or the second? And *why*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Split**, as many other English words, can be used both as a noun and as a verb.

All these sentences are fine:

> There's a split down the back of your jacket.
>
> Here's your split [=portion, share] of the proceeds.
>
> We agreed to a fifty-fifty split of the profit. [=we agreed to divide the profits equally]

Answer (score 2):

Both of these examples are correct. 'Split' can be used as both a noun and a verb.

In the case of:

> "Kosovo was a province of Yugoslavia before **its** split."

The use of the term "before its split" is valid as it refers to a time before Yugoslavia got 'split' (which is, as you stated, used as a noun).

Another example of this construction using a different noun might be:

> "Bob was an eager runner before **his** *illness*"

(The 'illness' being the noun) or:

> "Tech ltd was a part of Science co. before **its** *dissolution*"

(With 'dissolution' being a noun).

Meanwhile:

> "Kosovo was a province of Yugoslavia before **it** split"

This is, as you noticed, a perfectly fine use of a verb.

To adapt one of my examples from above:

> "Tech ltd was a part of Science co. before **it** *dissolved*"

This is another correct example, with 'dissolved' being the verb. If a noun were used there it wouldn't make sense, like this for example, which does *not* work:

> - "Tech ltd was a part of Science co. before **it** *dissolution*"